# MySQL : How to make a Having clause only filter by records in a Where clause?

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions, having

Suppose there is a table (dunder_sales) which tracks how many sales an employee in a well known paper company has made, here is a sample of its records..

```
 sale_id    emp_name       date_of_sale
   1001       Jim            04/23/2015
   1002       Dwight         04/28/2015
   1003       Dwight         05/11/2015
   1004       Phyllis        06/23/2015
```

Supposing a manager wants to see which employee had more than 30 sales in just the first quarter of 2015. Is there a query of this table for that?

If he just does..

```
SELECT emp_name, count(*)
FROM under_sales
WHERE date_of_sale > '2015-01-01'
    and date_of_sale < '2015-04-01'
GROUP BY emp_name
HAVING count(*) > 30
```

The count function used in the HAVING filter will count all the records, how can he make it count only the records in the where clause (only for that date range in the first quarter)?

Comment: What you're asking for is actually what happens. If you do a having clause with a count, the count will only count those records that have already passed the where clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code is ok. it just count only the records in the where clause.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried making it so count(*) has somethign easy to reference?

Like:

```
select 
emp_name, 
count(*) as records
FROM dunder_sales 
where date_of_sale > '2015-01-01' and date_of_sale < '2015-04-01' 
and records > 30
GROUP BY emp_name
```

Comment: You dropped the having clause?